# how to export data into CSV and PDF files using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, csv, pdf

I want to, when i click on button (separate for both CSV and PDF), it automatically download in CSV and PDF file with correct Formatting.
this CSV code i want to add PDF inside code

```
 $scope.downloadData = function() {
            var datasets = $scope.datasets.reverse();
            var file_name = $scope.m_id+ '.csv';
            var dataUrl = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,';
            var json = [];
            if(datasets !== null) {
                for(idx = 0; idx < datasets.length; idx++) {
                    var dataset = datasets[idx].data;
                    var time = datasets[idx].timestamp;
                    time = $filter('date')(time, "dd/MMMM/yyyy-hh:mm a");
                    dataset.time = time;
                    json.push(dataset);
            }
                var fields = Object.keys(json[0]);
                var csv = json.map(
                            function(row) {
                                return fields.map(
                                    function(fieldName) {
                                        return '"' + (row[fieldName] || '') + '"';
                                    }
                                );
                            }
                        );

                csv.unshift(fields);

                var csv_str = csv.join('%0A');
                var downloadURL = dataUrl + csv_str;

                var saveAs = function(uri, filename) {
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
                        document.body.appendChild(link); // Firefox requires the link to be in the body
                        link.download = filename;
                        link.href = uri;
                        link.target = "_blank";
                        link.click();
                        document.body.removeChild(link); // remove the link when done
                    } else {
                        location.replace(uri);
                    }
                };
                saveAs(downloadURL, file_name);
            } else {
               $scope.err_msg = 'Failed to get data. Try reloading the page.';
            }
        };
```

I try some of script i found on internet, but it is not working, some have formatting issue and save have downloading. 
In Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this awesome library for pdf/csv or whatever else formats.. [File Saver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver)

Here's is code example, service created using FileSaver

```
function download(api, file, contentType) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: api,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': contentType
        }
    }).success(function(response) {
        var data = new Blob([response], {
            type: contentType+ ';charset=utf-8'
        });
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, file);
        d.resolve(response);
    }).error(function(response) {
        d.reject(response);
    });
    return d.promise;
}
```

`file` input is name of file, you can use same service and pass the types and file names direct from controller.

Let;s you service name is `homeService`

for pdf call

`homeservice.download('/api/download/whaever', 'export.pdf', 'application/pdf')`

Comment: why use 3rd party library where there is javascript?

Comment: there are multiple options for anything in JS, I choose this solution over vanilla js, all about preference

Comment: sir i want to two option csv and pdf if i click csv then download csv file and if i click pdf download pdf file in only angularjs code

Comment: you must be calling some api for that