# Download csv format using Angularjs

Tags: mysql, angularjs, csv, export-to-csv

Node service: shown below are node service call where getting data from mysql query. And converting to json2csv format.

```
function getData(req,res){
        var json2csv = require('json2csv');
        var resultset = {};
        resultset.data = [];
        var nodeExcel=require('excel-export');
        var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
        var queryString = "select name ,class ,fname from details"

     connection.query(queryString, function(err, result) {
         if(err) {
                        console.log('error ',err);
                        resultset.success=false;
                            res.writeHead(200, {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                              });
                            var resultData =resultset;
                            res.write(JSON.stringify(resultData));
                              res.end();
                    } else {
                        if(result.length>0) {
                            for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
                                resultset.data[i]={};
                                var arr=_(result[i]).toArray();

                                resultset.data[i].name=arr[0]!=null?arr[0]:null;
                                resultset.data[i].class=arr[1]!=null?arr[1]:null;
                                resultset.data[i].fname=arr[2]!=null?arr[2]:null;
                            }
                            resultset.success=true;
                            res.writeHead(200, {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                              });
                            var resultData =json2csv(resultset);
                            console.log("resultData",resultData);
                            res.write(JSON.stringify(resultData));
                              res.end();
                        }   
                        else{
                            resultset.success = false;
                            res.writeHead(200, {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            });
                            var resultData = resultset;
                            res.write(JSON.stringify(resultData));
                            res.end();
                        }
                    }
            });


    }
```

Controller:

getting the service response.

```
$scope.Details=function(data,fileName){
    $http.get(Data.baseNodeService+'getData',headconfig).then(function(response,fileName){ 
    $scope.det = response.data.data;
    var element = angular.element('');
      var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
     anchor.attr({
         href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI($scope.det),
         target: '_blank',
         download: 'filename.csv'
     })[0].click();
    });
}
```

On click Html Download:

```
<input type="button" class="bt-submit" ng-click="Details()" value="Download" />
```

But I am getting download output as [object Object].I want to get data from my service call and download in csv format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download CSV in different ways, this below is a common way to download file

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.href = 'data:'+mimeType+';charset=utf-8;base64,' + response;
 a.target = '_blank';
 a.download = "name the file here";
 document.body.appendChild(a);
 a.click();
```

use the `mimeType` as your file type here for csv it would be `attachment/csv` but this won;t work on safari.

There is awseome library https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver You can use this.

You can call it like

```
function download(api, file, contentType) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: api,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': contentType
        }
    }).success(function(response) {
        var data = new Blob([response], {
            type: contentType+ ';charset=utf-8'
        });
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, file);
        d.resolve(response);
    }).error(function(response) {
        d.reject(response);
    });
    return d.promise;
}
```

Also see my other answers on file download

[how to export data into CSV and PDF files using angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621343/how-to-export-data-into-csv-and-pdf-files-using-angularjs/48621660?noredirect=1#comment84240419_48621660)

And

[AngularJS - Receive and download CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792681/angularjs-receive-and-download-csv/36793906#36793906)

Comment: what type of content you get from service response

Comment: I m getting response like ""\"name\",\"class\",\"fname\"…",\"abc\",\"nodeclass\"""

Comment: does that make sense ? what are you getting for csv means => base64 string or what ?

Comment: Use stackoverflow as a tool to get hints and logics not exact answers, just do a little research, you’ll get one of the above ways to work for you

Comment: Glad to help mate, that’s how you learn it, I would have given you right answer but what would you learn from that., right!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
/*this section for CSV*/
    if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob && window.Blob) {
        var blob = new Blob([response.data.data], {type: "text/csv"});
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, new Date().getTime() + '.csv');
    } else {
        var anchor = angular.element('<a/>').css({display: 'none'});
        angular.element(document.body).append(anchor); // Attach to document
        anchor.attr({
            href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(response.data.data),
            target: '_blank',
            download: new Date().getTime() + '.csv'
        })[0].click();
        anchor.remove();
    }
```

Comment: csvContent is undefine?

Comment: csvContent is your csv data variable and you have to write it in your controller

Comment: use your response.data.data at csvContent variable

Comment: file is downloading and giving output as [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]